# Is there a way to sort on any column other than the primary key of a table in Entity Framework 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework

I am working on Entity Framework 4.0 POCO and looking for a way to sort my grid on the list page with a field other than the primary key in the table/entity. I do not want to add a custom page though it is one of the solutions as that would be an overhead if this can be done otherwise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the following attribute.

I added a new attribute class for adding the sort column - **DefaultSortOrderColumn**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DefaultSortColumnAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DefaultSortColumnAttribute(string sortColumn, bool sortDescending)
    {
        this.SortColumn = sortColumn;
        this.SortDescending = sortDescending;
    }

    public string SortColumn { get; private set; }

    public bool SortDescending { get; private set; }
}
```

Then using this attribute for the partial entity class, i.e. the metadata class of your entity, for which we need to use the sort column

```
[DefaultSortColumn("YourSortColumn", false)]
public partial class YourDBEntity
{
}
```

We can then use this attribute in the PageTemplates\List.aspx to determine if there are any sortcolumns defined and sort with that in Page_Load.

```
MetaTable table = GridDataSource.GetTable();

if (!IsPostBack && table.Attributes.OfType<DefaultSortColumnAttribute>().Count() > 0)
{
    string sortColumn = table.Attributes.OfType<DefaultSortColumnAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().SortColumn;
    bool sortDescending = table.Attributes.OfType<DefaultSortColumnAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().SortDescending;
    GridView1.Sort(sortColumn, sortDescending ? SortDirection.Descending : SortDirection.Ascending);
}
```

This attribute can further be extended and set to the properties instead of the class. That way, we would be able to sort on multiple columns.

Thanks to those reponded. Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

If the result you are getting back is something like IEnumerable< YourPocoClass > or IQueryable< YourPocoClass >, you can always use .OrderBy(p => p.SomePropertyOtherThanPK)

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this :

```
var list = yourDbContext.YourDbSet.OrderBy(m=>m.Property);
```

Or if you wanna sort by string comes from the grid form by the client then you may use the Dynamic Linq:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx